# looking for 'sed' like functionality in Excel

Tags: excel, text, string-formatting

I use excel a lot to structure finite state machines. As such I often format cells so that I can cut and past entire sections into my C source directly.

Currently I'm having to preprocess one of my code blocks so that I can replace "-" with "_" in my identifiers.  Example, in cell I might have

```
#define Some-preprocessor-name
```

But I'd like to have:

```
#define SOME_PREPROCESSOR_NAME
```

The upper case bit is covered by UPPER(), but the locations of the hyphens is arbitrary as is the number I'd expect to find.  ***Suggestions?***

Comment: I don't know that you can do this easily in Excel, but why not just do it after you take it out of Excel?

Comment: I'm simply trying to remove a step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Substitute().

eg 
Substitute(A1, "-", "_")